# Simplify semi-boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm trying to simplify the following expression:

```
(A == B) OR ( (A > B) AND (A < C) )
```

Given that `B <= C`, this is my bet:

```
B <= A < C     (also  (B <= A) AND (A < C))
```

Explanation:

```
(A == B) OR ( (A > B) AND (A < C) )
((A == B) OR (A > B)) AND ((A == B) OR (A < C))
(A >= B) AND ((A == B) OR (A < C))
((A >= B) AND (A == B)) OR ((A >= B) AND (A < C))
(A >= B) OR ((A >= B) AND (A < C))
(A >= B) AND (A < C)
B <= A < C
```

Correct?

Basically, my assumptions are:

```
(A == B) OR  (A > B)   equals to  A >= B
(A >= B) AND (A == B)  equals to  A >= B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(A == B)\ OR\ (\ (A > B)\ AND\  (A < C)\ )$$
$$((A == B)\ OR\ (A > B))\ AND\ ((A == B)\ OR\ (A < C))$$
$$(A >= B)\ AND\ ((A == B)\ OR\ (A < C))$$

So these are your first two steps and I agree with them.  But I do not see where  you use $B <= C$, which would be key to the solution.
$$(A >= B)\ AND\ ((A == \color{RED}{B})\ OR\ (A < C))$$
$$(A >= B)\ AND\ ((A == \color{RED}{<= C})\ OR\ (A < C))$$
$$(A >= B)\ AND\ ((A <= C)\ OR\ (A < C))$$
$$(A >= B)\ AND\ (A <= C)$$
$$B <= A <= C$$

Comment: Indeed, good one!

Comment: I just followed your logic.  8)